# Is there a more idiomatic way to merge related rows from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I'm using a contrived example in order to illustrate the issue.

Imagine a simple table of books containing a title and subject/genre. In addition, there's an associated table of related subjects.

```
> SELECT * FROM books;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | title  | subject   |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Book A | science   |
|  2 | Book B | reference |
|  3 | Book C | fiction   |
+----+--------+-----------+

> SELECT * FROM related_subjects;
+----+---------+---------+
| id | book_id | subject |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 | physics |
|  2 |       1 | space   |
|  3 |       3 | crime   |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I'd like a query that could output all the title + subject combinations, so that it would look something like:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | title  | SUBJECT   |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Book A | science   |
|  1 | Book A | space     |
|  1 | Book A | physics   |
|  2 | Book B | reference |
|  3 | Book C | fiction   |
|  3 | Book C | crime     |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

The most obvious way, is to use a `UNION` as follows:

```
SELECT books.id, books.title, SUBJECT FROM books
UNION
SELECT books.id, books.title, related_subjects.subject FROM books
INNER JOIN related_subjects ON related_subjects.book_id = books.id;
```

Which yields a good result:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | title  | SUBJECT   |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Book A | science   |
|  2 | Book B | reference |
|  3 | Book C | fiction   |
|  1 | Book A | space     |
|  1 | Book A | physics   |
|  3 | Book C | crime     |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

However, it would be preferable if the natural output ordering was similar to my desired output, where the books row comes out first, followed by its related rows from the related_subjects table, and so on.

I'm curious as to whether there's a better/more efficient way of doing this sort of task? Particularly one that would give me a more natural ordering without having to apply a sort on the end result first.

Note: of course, I know I can apply a DB sort to the union output by ordering on books.id, related_subjects.id, but the output in my real world app consists of hundreds of thousands of rows, and so no harm in avoiding a relatively expensive sort if it can be avoided.

Comment: There is no such thing as *natural output ordering*. If you want your rows ordered, use *order by*... simple.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a computed column into the union query for ordering:

```sql
SELECT id, title, subject
FROM
(
    SELECT id, title, subject, 1 AS src FROM books
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id, b.title, rs.subject, 2
    FROM books b
    INNER JOIN related_subjects rs ON rs.book_id = b.id
) t
ORDER BY id, src;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a one-to-many relationship between books and subjects. So you could drop the subject column from the `books` table, and just make sure all the subjects that apply to the book are in the `related_subjects` table. Then you don't have to use UNION to get both, you just do the join from `book` to `related_subjects`.

In theory SQL does not guarantee any order of query results unless you specify the `ORDER BY`. But in practice, InnoDB returns rows in the order it reads them in the index it uses to look them up.